# create objects in a for loop c++

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I have this:

```
void Queue::testMethod(){
this->theQueue.clear();
for (int i = 0; i < 3 ; i ++ ){
    char *uu = new char[3];
    uu[0] = 'd';
    uu[1] = static_cast<char>(i);
    uu[2] = 'r';
    MyClass tt(uu, 7);
    this->theQueue.push_back(tt);

}

}

string Queue::PrintData(){
string data;
for ( int i = 0 ; i < this->theQueue.size(); i ++){
    data += this->theQueue.at(i).PrintData();
}

return data;
}
```

and this:

```
string MyClass::PrintData(){
string data;
data += string(this->AM);
data += " ";
data += this->Number;
return data;
}

MyClass::MyClass(char *am, int number) //Constructor
{
int i = strlen(am);
AM = new char[i+1];
strcpy(AM,am);
Number = number;
}
```

from the main I do the following:

```
MyClass myClass1((char *)"1111", 3);
MyClass myClass2((char *)"1111", 3);
MyClass myClass3((char *)"2222", 3);

vector<MyClass> tmpVector;
tmpVector.push_back(myClass1);
tmpVector.push_back(myClass2);
tmpVector.push_back(myClass3);

Queue tmpQueue(tmpVector);

tmpQueue.testMethod();
cout << tmpQueue.PrintData() << endl;
```

Are the objects tt inside the testMethod the same? Should I do destruct on every iteration? This is how c++ works but I get the following and I do not know why:

```
d dr dr
```

Comment: `int i = strlen(am);` requires am to be a nul terminated string which it isnt.

Answer (score 1):

You have undefined behaviour. In the constructor `MyClass::MyClass(char *am, int number)` you determine the string length via

```
int i = strlen(am);
```

C-style-strings are null-terminated. So this will look for a `\0` in `am`. This works for string literals like

```
MyClass myClass1((char *)"1111", 3);
```

because they automatically contain a terminating `\0`. In `Queue::testMethod()` the first iteration also works, because the second char

```
uu[1] = static_cast<char>(i);
```

is a null-character (since `i` is `0` at this point). `strlen` finds this null-character at index 1, thus returns a length of 1 and thus only `r` get's printed. For any `i > 0` the buffer `uu` does *not* contain a terminating null-character, so `strlen` is reading outside the array bounds, which is undefined behaviour.